# Trying to make a panning window with CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to make a window that will display a number of show listings, panning through each with left and right scroll buttons. The problem is, when I place two listing layouts within the frame, it doesn't add them side by side at their full size with a scrollbar as I would expect. Instead, it distorts both so they will fit in the same space.

EDIT: I thought it might be prudent to mention that the ultimate goal here is to get a list of show objects from a server, and the number can vary. So, the width of the div holding them will have to adapt to the change.

Here is what I'm after, with one in view:
[image]

Here is what is actually happening:
[image]

The color gradient is only there so I can see what I'm doing. Once I'm sure they're panning correctly, it'll be changed to transparent. Below is my code. If anyone can offer any advice, I'd appreciate it.

Shows.js:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import styles from './Shows.module.css';

const Shows = () => {
    const Show = (details) => {
        return (
            <div className={styles.showMain}>
                <div className={styles.posterFrame} style={null /* SET BACKGROUND IMAGE HERE, COVER??? */}/>
                <div className={styles.textFrame}>
                    TEST
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.main} id="shows">
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.banner}>
                    <h1 className={styles.bannerText}>UPCOMING SHOWS</h1>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.scrollButton}>&lt;</div>
                    <div className={styles.showBody}>{Show(null)}</div>
                    <div className={styles.showBody}>{Show(null)}</div>
                    <div className={styles.scrollButton}>&gt;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shows
```

Shows.module.css:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), linear-gradient(112.78deg, rgba(183, 35, 35, 0.5) 12.87%, rgba(51, 169, 236, 0.5) 52.53%, rgba(74, 183, 35, 0.5) 97.84%), url("../../public/images/concert1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* ---------------- Scrolling frame ---------------- */

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 82.5%;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.scrollContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    display: flex;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bannerText {
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: rgba(50, 236, 191, 1);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(183, 35, 35, 1);
}

.scrollButton {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}

.scrollButton:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}

.showBody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* ---------------- Show listing ---------------- */

.showMain {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000 -9.27%, rgba(34, 255, 0, 1) 112.68%);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.posterFrame {
    height: 90%;
    width: 35%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.textFrame {
    height: 90%;
    width: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. In combination with the suggestions here, which got me to the side by side display I was after, I placed the two `Show` items in a new div with the className `showWindow`. I set the CSS for the window as follows:

```
.showWindow {
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This displays one at a time, gives me the scrollbar, and does not obstruct the scroll buttons. Thanks for helping me find the solution, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
.scrollContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This not going to work, you need make it like so:

```
.scrollContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 90%;
    //width: 100%; < wrong
    //overflow: hidden; < wrong
    overflow-x:auto;
    flex-wrap:no-wrap;

}
```

Then

```
.showMain {
    height: 100%;
    //width: 100% !important;
    width: 300px; // sorry I have to be specified
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000 -9.27%, rgba(34, 255, 0, 1) 112.68%);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Though it's undoubtedly a smarter way to approach it, it's resulting in the same problem. Setting width to 900px gives me the same result as width: 100%. Is there a reason width has to be specified like that?

Comment: Yes, flex would divide items width to fix it’a maximum

Answer (score 0):

Update the css:

```
.scrollContainer {
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}

.showBody {
  ...
  flex: none;
}

.scrollButton {
  ...
  flex: none;
}

.sliderContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then wrap the content with a `sliderContainer`:

```
<div className={styles.sliderContainer}>
  <div className={styles.scrollButton}>&lt;</div>
  <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
    <div className={styles.showBody}>{Show(null)}</div>
    <div className={styles.showBody}>{Show(null)}</div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.scrollButton}>&gt;</div>
</div>
```

And it [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-tharp-sgoe7d?file=/src/App.module.css).

Comment: Well, that gives me the side by side display I was after. The trouble is, it's covering the scroll buttons, and it isn't contained to that central window. What I'm after is showing one at a time, and the scroll buttons will pan back and forth between them. That functionality hasn't been created yet, but for now, I'd settle for a scroll bar for that central window.

Comment: Then you need another `div`. I have updated the answer.